# Cordova 3.5.0 - FAILED renaming /storage/emulated/0/tmprecording.3gp

Tags: android, cordova

I've scoured the net looking for others with similar problems.  I've found similar error messages, but nobody has seen to found any answers.  This seems to be a common error message with both the Cordova 2.x series and 3.x series.  I get this error when I try to record audio using Cordova's org.apache.cordova.media plugin.  Specifically, after creating a media object, running startRecord(), and then when I execute stopRecord(), that is when the error occurs.

```
function recordJournalAudio() {
    var mediaRecFile = 'journalEntry-' + app.nextJournalID + '.amr';
    if (!app.recording) {
        app.mediaRec = new Media(mediaRecFile, function() {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
            },
            function(err) {
                console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
            }
        );

        $("#recordJournalAudioBtn").button("option", "theme", "b");

        // Record audio
        app.mediaRec.startRecord();
        app.recording = true;
    }
    if (app.recording) {
        app.mediaRec.stopRecord(); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        $("#recordJournalAudioBtn").button("option", "theme", "a");
    }       
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: suggestion: add the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> ` permission in android manifest

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that permission is already in the manifest and I verified it in the app settings on the device.

Comment: I also get this error when playing different audio than the recorded one. The AudioPlayer class attempts to rename the recording into the audio that is playing.

Comment: @WilliamWhite I reported this since 2.9 but no fix yet https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/gy_uBibensk, anyway my app is working regardless so I forgot about this

Answer (score 3):

William - This is an error/bug with the implementation within the plugin. I ran across your question while I was looking for a solution to this for my own project.

The issue lies in the fact that a temp file is created initially to write the audio to, then it is moved and renamed after finishing recording. The File.renameTo() function that is used will not write from internal to SD (or vis versa). I have rewritten the function for my own purposes and it is working great as far as I can see. Below is the updated function.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/master/src/android/AudioPlayer.java

org.apache.cordova.media > AudioPlayer.java Line 32 (add)

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
```

org.apache.cordova.media > AudioPlayer.java Line 139 (replace)

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
   this.audioFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file;
   } 
else {
      this.audioFile = "/data/data/" + handler.cordova.getActivity().getPackageName() + "/cache/" + file;
   }            
   //this.audioFile = file;
```

org.apache.cordova.media > AudioPlayer.java Line 168 (replace entire function)

```
public void moveFile(String file) {
/* this is a hack to save the file as the specified name */
File newf = new File(file);
String folder = newf.getParent();

if (folder == null) folder = "";

File CheckDirectory;
  CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
  if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
  { 
   CheckDirectory.mkdir();
  }


String logMsg = "renaming " + this.tempFile + " to " + file;
Log.d(LOG_TAG, logMsg);

 InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(this.tempFile));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FAILED  to open INPUT stream: " + logMsg);
}

 OutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FAILED to open OUTPUT stream: " + logMsg);
}

 // Transfer bytes from in to out
 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
 int len; try {
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);

    in.close();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "FAILED COPY: " + logMsg);
}

}
```

Let me know if this takes care of your issue as well.

Comment: I tried this proposal, it only changed the output for me: Failed to open INPUT and Failed to open OUTPUT. Android 4.4 device.

Comment: How can I modify the source code before adding the media plugin via the command line? I am using 3.5, I also need to do other changes to the AudioPlayer class to fit my needs

Comment: Seems not to be working for me, reading a .wav file from www/audio under Cordova 4.1.2 See http://pastebin.ca/2895895